# How to improve load performance in experience editor

Tags: experience-editor

When I open page in experience editor it takes 3 to 4 minutes to load the page . Is there any suggestions to improve performance of the page in EE?

Comment: Start with this one: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/improving-the-performance-of-myitems-count-in-sitecore-8-1
Then check in your network tab which requests take most time

Answer (score 1):

It always takes a lot of time to load Experience Editor first time, but if you experiencing this problem each page refresh, then you can try:

1. Set "WebEdit.ShowNumberOfLockedItemsOnButton" setting to "false"
2. Set "ContentTesting.AutomaticContentTesting.Enabled" setting to "false"

Note: each version of the Sitecore might require different fixes.

Answer (score 0):

There can be too many root causes. If you don't find the solution in the links that have been shared with you, I would recommend that you do your own research, each instance is a different world.

1. Enable and check the Sitecore pipeline profiler.
2. Open the page in debug mode (Sitecore).
3. Use advanced tools (dotTrace, ANTS, Visual Studio, etc).

Sometimes it's a custom (bad) code implemented on any of your custom components that take long to execute. There is a data source query that is very expensive, etc.. Root causes can be infinite, but those tools would definitely help you to find and fix your performance issues.

Comment: I used the Jet brains tool to calculate the server side code performance time and resolved the issue. Jet brains helps to find which internal methods and pipelines called during the page load in experience editor mode.